# C++: What takes up more memory, storing a single character as char or string?

Tags: c++, string, memory, char

I am writing code, where different parts of the code are executed depending on user input. If I am sure that the user will only input a single character, will a string or char take up more memory? Are there any other advantages of one way to another?

EDIT:
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
using namespace std;
char operation;//or string
cout << "enter the operator (+/=):" << endl;
cin >> operation;
if (operation == '+') {
//do something
}
else {
//do something else
}
```

Comment: Post some code please?

Comment: It's going to be rather difficult to shove an entire `std::string` into a lonely, single `char`.

Comment: Do you have any reasons to think that the application is starved for memory? If not, do whatever is easier for you.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI a C++ string doesn't use 4 bytes. A char will be one byte though.

Comment: A string is a sequence of chars. How could that take less memory than a single char in any circumstance?

Comment: @JonChesterfield: depending on how it's allocated, your single char may also end up taking up 16 bytes or so... it really depends on all the details.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can see one byte of char and N bytes padding. Stack alignment / end of structure alignment padding / malloc implementation. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @JonChesterfield: yes, right. So if you're actually concerned about memory pressure, the issue isn't as easy as just looking at the object sizes.

Comment: @KerrekSB yep, agreed. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What takes up more memory, storing a single character as char or string?

`char` is by definition the size of the smallest addressable memory unit on the system. Therefore no object can take up less memory.

String is a sequence of characters. An array of single element takes exactly as much memory as a single element:

```
char c = 'a';
char str[] = {'a'};
assert(sizeof c == sizeof str);
```

However, most uses of a character string requires that the string is terminated by the null character. There is exactly one string that includes the null terminator, and fits in an array of single character: The empty string.

Therefore, unless the character that the user inputs is null, the string must necessarily use more memory than a single character - if you need it to be null terminated.

---

In case you are considering `std::string`, that contains a few pointers (which are larger than a byte on most systems) in addition to the buffer that contains the characters themselves. (Although, the implementation may be optimized such that no external buffer is allocated for small strings)

> Are there any other advantages of one over the other?

The main advantage of `std::string` over `char` is that the former can represent strings of arbitrary length, rather than a single character.

Answer (score 3):

A `char` takes a single byte.
An `std::string` takes at least `sizeof(std::string)` bytes, which is probably 24 bytes on a modern PC.

In your case the saved memory quite likely doesn't matter (because the saving will be very minimal, probably 23 bytes), so you should stick to what describes your intent best. If you need a single character, then a single `char` would make sense.

Comment: `sizeof(std::string) == 28` on my machine (VC++2015)

Comment: Are there any other advantages of one over the other? (for example performance?)

Comment: @kyczawon `char` is quite likely faster.